# why does std::search need forward iters

Tags: c++, iterator, forward

my issue is identical to the thread below, I'm struggling to understand the answers given, or rather my code shouldn't work as it only uses input iterators ..but my func appears to work and behave identically to std::search ..so I'm at a loss and loathe to move on without understanding properly ...maybe if someone can suggest an input that will break my function but not the std::

From [Why do I need a Forward Iterator to implement my customized std::search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795114/why-do-i-need-a-forward-iterator-to-implement-my-customized-stdsearch) :

> I am studying the book "Accelerated
>   C++" from Koenig & Moo.
>
> Exercise 8-2 ask me to implement on my
>   own some templatized functions from
>   <algorithm> and <numeric>, and to
>   specify what kind of iterator does my
>   implementation require.
>
> When trying to implement std::search,
>   I determined that I need only "input"
>   iterators.
>
> However, looking at the implementation
>   of std::search installed with my
>   compiler, I can see that they use
>   "forward" iterators, but I cannot
>   understand why, because there is no
>   need to write, only to read, and input
>   iterators meet the requirement.
>
> Can anybody here help me to understand
>   this, please? Why would I need to use
>   "forward" iterators to implement
>   std::search?
>
> Thanks in advance.

myfunction:

```
template <class In> 
In search(  In begin, In end, In begin2, In end2 )
{
    In found ;                      // iter: 1st element in pattern match(in content)
    In pattern_begin = begin2 ;     // iter: 1st element in search pattern.
    int flag = 0 ;                  // flag: partial match found?

    // search content for pattern 
    while (  begin < end  ) {

        // if pattern-match fails ..reset vars
        // & continue searching remaining content/elements
        if ( *begin != *begin2 ) {

            In ret ;                     
            begin2 = pattern_begin ;
            flag = 0 ;
            begin++ ;


        } else {
            // compare next element in pattern with next element in content.
            // if: 1st element of 'pattern' is found, store iter to it's pos
            // ..then if entire pattern is found, we can ret an iter to where it starts
            if ( flag == 0 ) { 
                found = begin ;
                flag = 1 ;
            }
            // inc iters to compare next elements in partial match
            begin++ ;
            begin2++ ;
        }

        // if: iter is 1-past end of search pattern
        // then entire pattern has been found 
        // return the iter to where it starts
        if( begin2 == end2 ) {  return found ;  }

    }

    // end of content reached, no complete pattern found
    // begin should? equal an iter 1-past the end of content
    return begin ;
}
```

driver:

```
///* // Driver: custom::search(  b, e, b2, e2  ) 
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
//#include <algorithm>
#include "library_algorithms.h"

int main() {

    // init string test
    std::string content = "fo The fox  foxu jumped  foxe foxy " ;
    std::string search_pattern = "foxy" ;

    // func test on string
    std::string::iterator ret_iter = 
    custom::search(  content.begin(), content.end(), search_pattern.begin(), search_pattern.end()  ) ;
    //std::search(  content.begin(), content.end(), search_pattern.begin(), search_pattern.end()  ) ;

    // output
    if (  ret_iter != content.end()  ) {

        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << search_pattern << ": found at position: " << int(  ret_iter - content.begin()  ) << std::endl;

    } else { 

        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << search_pattern << ": ...not found" << std::endl;
    }




    // Init vec test:
    // create content values in range:  10 20 30 <......> 9970 9980 9990
    std::vector<int> myvector;
    for (int i=1; i<1000; i++) myvector.push_back(i*10);

    // create pattern values to search for
    std::vector<int> pattern ;
    pattern.push_back( 3730 ) ;
    pattern.push_back( 3740 ) ;
    pattern.push_back( 3750 ) ;
    pattern.push_back( 3760 ) ;

    // test: func on vector<int>
    std::vector<int>::iterator it;
    it = custom::search (  myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), pattern.begin(), pattern.end() );

    // output
    if (it!=myvector.end())
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << "pattern found at position " << int(it-myvector.begin()) << std::endl;
    else
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << "pattern not found" << std::endl;





    return 0 ;

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've misunderstood what an input iterator can do.

You can't "save" or copy an input iterator. It allows you to traverse the sequence exactly once. In other words, this line, among others, will break: `begin2 = pattern_begin`.

An input iterator may represents something that you can't readily "rewind", like, say, the stream of data received from a network adapter. An iterator pointing to "6 elements ago" is no longer meaningful, because that data may no longer be available in memory. You only have the *current* position in the stream.

It should be obvious that in order to implement `search` correctly, you need to be able to traverse parts of the sequence more than once.

Comment: it seems obvious ...but myfunction seems quite happy to traverse the search sequence more than once ..when it finds partial matches ..it resets when the pattern match is broken...until it finds a complete match...

Comment: sry struggling with forum abit....I'v added the driver to my op that shows myfunc finding a complete match ..at the end of multiple partial/incomplete matches...maybe if you can suggest an input that will break my func ..I can step thro to better understand

Comment: @tuk: yes but you're calling the function with random-access iterators (string and vector iterators). Try calling it with `std::input_iterator` for example. Of course, if your code depends on features found on forward iterators, and you call it with something *stronger* than a forward iterator, it'll work fine. ;) You'll need to actually pass an input iterator to your function in order to see if it works with input iterators. :)

Comment: @tuk: Or consider what happens if the input comes from the keyboard. How could you go back and reread what I typed before? It's gone! That's why we have a separate input_iterator category, that is single pass.

Comment: er, that should've been `std::istream_iterator`, of course. Or `std::istreambuf_iterator`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation guys ..that makes a lot more sense now ...I was wrongly assuming the vec iters would be cast to whatever type was defined in the function template

Comment: @tuk: you don't define a type in the function template. `In` (I assume that's what you're referring to) has no special significance. It's just the name by which you want to refer to the first template parameter. You're just saying "define a function `search`, which takes a single template type parameter, which I'm going to call `In`)

Comment: thanks again jaif for clearing that up ..the book is good but it doesn't go into enough detail on this for me